# exception org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Injection of persistence dependencies failed is thrown

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a module which uses Spring and using maven builds in separate jar.
Spring and other libraries are located outside the jar file in separate folder.
in general it looks like this:

***target***
|---*lib*
|---*updater.jar*

The problem is, when I run this jar using following command
**java -jar updater-1.jar com.updater.config.Application**
it starts to execute but stops with following exception:

```
2015-03-05 09:10:35,966 ERROR      [Application.java:40] - Error creating bean with name 
'scheduledTask': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: 
private com.updater.manager.UpdateManager com.updater.config.ScheduledTask.updateManager; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:    
Error creating bean with name 'updateManager': Injection of autowired dependencies 
failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: 
private com.updater.persistence.repository.CommonEntityRepository 
com.updater.manager.UpdateManager.commonEntityRepository; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'commonEntityRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception 
is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean 
of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined - 
[main] com.updater.config.ScheduledTask
```

**btw:** exception is thrown only when I run app from generated jar file. If I run it from IDE (Intellij Idea) app works correctly without this exception.

```java
package com.updater.config;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.updater")
// cannot read external properties by relative path
@PropertySource(name = "external1", value = "file:external.properties",     
ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
@Import({ PersistenceConfig.class })
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Scheduler:

```java
package com.updater.config;

@Component
public class ScheduledTask {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    @Autowired
    private UpdateManager updateManager;
    ...
}
```

UpdateManager:

```java
package com.updater.manager;

@Component
public class UpdateManager {       
    @Autowired
    private ChangesService changesService;
    @Autowired
    private CommonEntityRepository commonEntityRepository;
    ...
}
```

CommonEntityRepository:

```java
package com.updater.persistence.repository;

@Component
public class CommonEntityRepository {
    @Value(value = "${identity.insert.enable.sql:}")
    private String identityInsertEnableSql;
    @Value("${identity.insert.disable.sql:}")
    private String identityInsertDisableSql;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    ...
}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

generated Manifest.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: updater
Implementation-Version: 1
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: Author
Specification-Vendor: SoftwareEntwicklung Beratung Schulung
groupId: com.updater.service
Specification-Title: updater
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.updater.service
Class-Path: 
    lib/jsr305-2.0.1.jar 
    lib/spring-boot-starter-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar 
    lib/spring-boot-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar 
    lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar 
    lib/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar  
    lib/spring-core-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar 
    lib/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar 
    lib/spring-data-jpa-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar 
    lib/spring-data-commons-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar 
    lib/spring-orm-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar 
    lib/spring-jdbc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar 
    lib/spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar 
    lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar 
    lib/spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar 
    lib/spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar 
    ...
version: 1
Implementation-Vendor: SoftwareEntwicklung Beratung Schulung
Main-Class: com.updater.config.Application
artifactId: updater
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.5
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_31
Specification-Version: 1
```

**UPDATED**

To better understand what is going on I had no other choice like to debug Spring where this exception is produced.

I found that there is some difference in initialization between executing app gtom IDE and as separate jar.

Spring loads some factories

[image]

and there is some difference in urls variable

top is IDE debugging
bottom is remote jar debugging

[image]

so some jars are not considered.
Looks like it is problem with class-path. but as for me manifest is correct.

At this point I don't know where to move next.

Comment: Did you open the updater.jar using any unzipper and verified whether the respective dependency jars(in Manifest) are included in proper path inside jar?

Comment: thanks for reply. but folder with libs is outside of the jar file. And because of updater.jar and libs are on the same level, manifest contains following line as class-path: lib/spring-boot-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar. That was an idea to separate libs and updater.jar (because of autoupdate)